# index.php is not receiving the JSON sent by the backbone Post

Tags: json, backbone.js

I've been trying to understand how Backbone works and communicates with the back-end code, and I have an issue of not being able to receive the JSON I send to my php file.

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Understanding Backbone</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #fff; }

h2 { font-family: Abel, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 5px 0;}
input { background-color: #ddd; border: 0; }
input:active { background-color: #bbb; }

#new-status { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background-color: #67A9C3; }
#statuses { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background-color: #92B456; }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="new-status">
<h2>New monolog</h2>
<form>
    <textarea id="status" name="status"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="statuses">
    <h2>Monologs</h2>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var Status = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'api/index.php'
});

var Statuses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Status
});

var NewStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "submit form": "addStatus"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection.on("add", this.clearInput, this);
    },

    addStatus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() });
    },

    clearInput: function() {
        this.$('textarea').val('');
    }
});

var StatusesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection.on("add", this.appendStatus, this);
    },

    appendStatus: function(status) {
        this.$('ul').append('<li>' + status.escape("text") + '</li>');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var statuses = new Statuses();
    new NewStatusView({ el: $('#new-status'), collection: statuses });
    new StatusesView({ el: $('#statuses'), collection: statuses });
});
```

index.php:

```
<?php

echo(var_dump($_POST));

?>
```

This is what I get for the response:

array(0) {
}

I've been breaking my head over this, so please HELP!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, try to abstract a bit your real problem, add it to the question and change the question title to match it. This way you can have better changes to get people to answer your question.

Comment: I've edited the best I could, added more code....

Comment: I think I found my own answer, Backbone does not send a "post" request it sends a set of headers so you have to find out what the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is than proceed from there.

Thanks to the community!!! 

Stevo

Comment: After the edits the question looks good doesn't deserve a downvote anymore. Wish I could help!

Comment: Ok so here is the PHP:
<?php
$requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
switch ($requestMethod) {
 case 'POST':
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 echo $data;
 break;
}
?>

Comment: Backbone will make GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests depending on the model state and the method used. Have you considered using a RESTful php framework (E.g. My preference, Slim PHP microframework)? It makes working with Backbone a LOT easier.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer, so it can help others.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research on stackoverflow(awesome community btw) I was able to find that backbone does not send straight post or get to the RESTful api, or whatever the code-behind might be, but instead it is a set of headers. So you have to poke around the $_SERVER global and find out what is being requested. You'll be able to find your request in the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], than perform a switch/case to decide what you want to do with that request. The data being sent through (in backbone's case is always a JSON string) is in the HTTP body and to get it out I used the file_get_contents('php://input'), and decode the JSON so that php can work with it.

```
<?php 
$requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];     
switch ($requestMethod) 
{ 
case 'POST': $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
echo $data; 
break; 
} 
?>
```

@orangewarp, I really wanted to understand what was happening under the hood without using a  RESTful php framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
$raw_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($raw_data);
if( !empty($raw_data) ){
    $data = @json_decode($raw_data, true);
    if( $data ){
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```