# Decode backbone.js JSON package in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, backbone.js

So, I've been having trouble decoding valid JSON requests sent to the server from a backbone.js application. No matter what I tried, the decoded $_POST data returned null. I poked around stackoverflow and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162132/index-php-is-not-receiving-the-json-sent-by-the-backbone-post):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
print_r($data);
```

This seems like a hack so I am wondering if there is a better way to handle JSON data from backbone in PHP. What is the proper way to recieve and decode JSON data sent from a backbone.js application in PHP?

Comment: I'm using that solution too, I don't think there's a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for the request method used to send data to your script, like this:

```
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    case 'POST':
    {
      // do something
    }
    break;

    case 'GET':
    {
      // do something else
    }
    break;

    case 'PUT':
    {
      // your snippet goes here
    }
    break;

    case 'DELETE':
    {
      // do something when request method == DELETE
    }
    break;
}
```

The code you posted is what you should use for when REQUEST_METHOD is PUT or DELETE. It's not a hack at all.

You can also configure Backbone to send data via POST with:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
```

From Backbone's manual:

> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support
>   Backbone's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on
>   Backbone.emulateHTTP. Setting this option will fake PUT and DELETE
>   requests with a HTTP POST, setting the X-HTTP-Method-Override header
>   with the true method. If emulateJSON is also on, the true method will
>   be passed as an additional _method parameter.

Comment: My api is RESTful, I was just more concerned with the inability to access get/post/put the normal way.

Comment: Well, the simple answer is: you can't access PUT and DELETE without reading php://input

Comment: More info in PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php